# Long running Beanstalk worker jobs and deploys

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running long jobs on Beanstalk Worker Tier. I have set the VisibilityTimeout, InactivityTimeout and nginx timeouts to 10 hours - this is working as expected. The ErrorVisibilityTimeout is set at 30 seconds, as I want messages to be immediately redelivered should the processing fail.

However, when deploying, or if an instance fails & is replaced by Beanstalk, the ErrorVisibilityTimeout is not respected & the message remains in flight for 10 hours when it is indeed reprocessed.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I achieve the message being redelivered 30 seconds after an instance removal / failure ?

Comment: how did you manage to set nginx timeout? My .ebextensions just being ignored ;(

Comment: use .platform instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you can't change message timeout in case instance fails. This is because `ErrorVisibilityTimeout` parameter is specific to EB. It is not a property of SQS. So the way EB worker works is that SQS daemon on an EB instance will receive the message from the queue, and then pass it to your app. In the app returns http code 200 OK, the daemon will delete the message from the queue.

However, if your app returns fails to process the message, the daemon returns the message to the queue. This is done by daemon using [ChangeMessageVisibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) to reduce the visibility timeout of the message so that it becomes visible quickly again, despite 10h default visibility timeout.

Since instance fails or is terminated, there is nothing that can call `ChangeMessageVisibility` to reduce the visibility timeout and the message stays in its default 10h timeout.

Comment: another great beanstalk UX choice I guess :( sad